# Why $U''(ξ) + 1/2\xi U' (\xi) + 1/2 U (\xi) = 0$ is invariant under $\xi = -\xi?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why $U''(ξ) + \frac{1}{2}\xi U' (\xi) + \frac{1}{2} U (\xi) = 0$ is invariant wrt to change of variables $\xi = -\xi?$ I think there is no additional information about $U.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace $\xi\rightarrow -\xi$ and see if the equation changes. If not the equation considered is invariant under this transformation.

More clearly

$$\frac{\partial ^2 U}{\partial \xi^2}+\frac{\xi}{2}\frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi}+\frac{1}{2}U=0 \tag1$$

Performing this change you obtain:
$$\frac{\partial ^2 U}{(\partial -\xi)^2}+\frac{(-\xi)}{2}\frac{\partial U}{(\partial -\xi)}+\frac{1}{2}U=0$$
Which is the same as $(1)$

I know that this is mathematically incorrect but visually it has a lot of potential. This should have been done applying the chain rule, proposing the change of variable $\xi=-s$, for example.

Regarding the function $U$, additional information is not required, because $U$ depends on $\xi$, and after the change it would depend on $s$.

Comment: By $\partial U/(\partial - \xi)$ you mean $\partial U/\partial (- \xi)$, right?

Comment: shouldn't U be even ?? $ U(x)=U(-x) $

Comment: @ConnorHarris  yes of course... Thank yu for the remark. I didn't know how to put the short minus sign. The operation $\partial - \xi$ has no sense anyways...

Comment: @JoseGarcia The sign of $U$ isn't relevant here. In fact $U$ can be even or odd. When the equation is solved you can see it.